# How to add a property data: for json?

Tags: c#, list, object

I've created a list of object in C# but I'm struggling to understand how I can add a property (that may not be the right term) to the beginning of it:

This might be really obvious and I'm not sure what I need to Google! Any help would be appreciated!

What I'm trying to do:

```
{
'data' : [  <--Add this in (is this a property of the object?)
  {
    'valueName1': 'value1',
    'valueName2': 'value2',
    'valueName3': 'value3',
   },
   {
    'valueName1': 'value1',
    'valueName2': 'value2',
    'valueName3': 'value3',
   },
 ]}
```

What I've got currently!

```
[  
  {
    'valueName1': 'value1',
    'valueName2': 'value2',
    'valueName3': 'value3',
   },
   {
    'valueName1': 'value1',
    'valueName2': 'value2',
    'valueName3': 'value3',
   },
 ]
```

This is what I've got in C# at the moment:

```
result= new List<TestList> { };

            foreach (var issueData2 in myDeserializedClass.issues)
            {
                result.Add(new TestList { valueName1 = issueData2.fields.summary, 
                                          valuename2 = issueData2.fields.created,
                                          valuename3 = issueData2.fields.updated, });
               
            }
 
        string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newtonresult);
```

With this class:

```
public class TestList
    {
        public String valuename1 { get; set; }
        public String valuename2 { get; set; }
        public String valuename3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `public class Wrapper { public List<TestList> Data { get; set;}}`?

Comment: Did you try something like this ?  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

Comment: The simplest solution I can think of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { data = newtonresult });`

Comment: Yes, but what is `newtonresult` when the variable above is called `result` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't violate C# naming conventions (properties have PascalCaseNames) just to get your JSON to appear correctly; common json serializers support attributes that allow you to name your C# properties differently to json:

```
public class TestList
{
    [JsonProperty("valuename1")] 
    public String ValueName1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("valuename2")]
    public String ValueName2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("valuename1")]
    public String ValueName3 { get; set; }
}
```

..that's if you even need to; you can usually also configure serializers so they produce camelCaseJsonPropertyNames even if the C# names are PascalCase - [for example](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategySkipSpecifiedNames.htm)

And as GSerg comments, you can put your testlist list in another class:

```
public class Wrapper { 
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<TestList> Data { get; set;}
}
```

Then have a creation of:

```
        result= new List<TestList> { };

        foreach (var issueData2 in myDeserializedClass.issues)
        {
            result.Add(new TestList { valueName1 = issueData2.fields.summary, 
                                      valuename2 = issueData2.fields.created,
                                      valuename3 = issueData2.fields.updated, });
           
        }

        var ser = new Wrapper { Data = result };

        string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ser);
```

You actually don't even need the class Wrapper, if you want.. You can also use an anonymous type:

```
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new{ data = result });
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you basically want property **data** which is an array of object TestList class

```
public class Test{
  public IEnumerable<TestList> data {get; set'}
}
```

Now you can serialize the data

```
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject<Test>(newtonresult);
```